# Using more Stored Procedure will affect on performance of application?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is using more stored procedure in an application will cause the low performance of the application ? Is it reduces the speed of web application ?

I am Using SQL server 2005 database

Comment: See these Pros/Cons of different queries. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2934666/1504882

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server basically goes through these steps to execute **any** query (stored procedure call or ad-hoc SQL statement):

1. syntactically check the query
2. if it's okay - it checks the plan cache to see if it already has an execution plan for that query
3. if there is an execution plan - that plan is (re-)used and the query executed
4. if there is no plan yet, an execution plan is determined
5. that plan is stored into the plan cache for later reuse
6. the query is executed

The point is: ad-hoc SQL and stored procedures are treatly **no differently**.

If an ad-hoc SQL query is properly using **parameters** - as it should anyway, to prevent SQL injection attacks - its performance characteristics are **no different** and most definitely **no worse** than executing a stored procedure.

Stored procedure have other benefits (no need to grant users direct table access, for instance), but in terms of performance, using properly parametrized ad-hoc SQL queries is **just as efficient** as using stored procedures.

Using stored procedures over **non-parametrized** queries is better for two main reasons:

- since each non-parametrized query is a **new, different** query to SQL Server, it has to go through all the steps of determining the execution plan, for each query (thus wasting time - and also wasting plan cache space, since storing the execution plan into plan cache doesn't really help in the end, since that particular query will probably **not** be executed again)
- non-parametrized queries are at risk of SQL injection attack and should be avoided at all costs

Answer (score 0):

Using more stored procedures" then what is necessary?, then yes this will impact your application.

If all your required data you are retrieving is via stored procedures then this, for the most, will be the best way to retrieve data.

You could also answer that, yes, removing stored procedures would speed up your application but I'm sure would not work or have a lot less content / functionality...

I would focus more on how your database is designed.

Ensure referential integrity (set up relationships between your tables).

Make use of primary keys and indexes.

These are the things which will have real impact in speeding up your application, for the data retrieval part anyway.